# How to access a table in linq

Tags: linq

I need to clone a table of a database which exists in a different servers.
e.g.On server A there is a database called EmployeeDataBase which has a table t1 which I need to copy to the database called EmployeeDataBase which exists on Server B.
How to do it using linq query.

My application uses linq to entity.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the tables have the same definition you can use the same mappings, just you need to create different contexts using the appropriate connection strings.

```
var ctxSource = new  EmployeeDataBaseContext("[source connection]");
var ctxDestination = new  EmployeeDataBaseContext("[destination connection]");

ctxDestination.t1.InsertAllOnSubmit(ctxSource.t1.ToList());
ctxDestination.SubmitChanges();
```

Check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.datacontext.aspx) the constructors you need.

Comment: Let me elaborate:I have a textbox for server name,username and password required for a connection.When a user after filling up these textboxes clicks on a dropdown I check the connection and load all the databases in a database dropdown.Now User selects a source database from the givend dropdown.when  a user selects on a particular database all the distinct rows of that database should be populate in other dropdown.

Comment: so you don't know in advance the database schema

Comment: DataContext lnqDC = new System.Data.Linq.DataContext("Data Source=" + serverName + ";Initial Catalog=master;User Id=" + serverUserName + ";Password=" + serverPassWord + ";"); 
            var DatabaseNames = lnqDC.ExecuteQuery<string>("select[name] from sys.databases").AsEnumerable();I did this to list all the databases of a server.

Comment: this is totally another problem

Comment: Got it.I did exactly what you told on the first answer.

Comment: can you help me with this linq query:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38120664/how-to-group-by-on-2-child-entities-and-get-total-of-both-this-child-entities

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework is not the right technology for this kind of problem. You will be better off using raw ADO.Net. Maybe SqlBulkCopy can be of use: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx